# How to install latex setup on linux from a disk

Tags: installing, linux

I have some RHEL computers I need to install latex on. These may be converted to CentOS but there is no guarantee.

As a requirement for the install I can't use the internet to install it. I must have a disk (or a set of disks) to install. What is the best way to approach this?

There will be a lot of latex use for many different documents (lots of math, tables, images). I want a comprehensive install to start so I'm not constantly adding new packages. This is a small subset of things I know I want:

- pdflatex
- makeindex
- bibtex
- makeglossaries
- glossary
- glossary-extra

How do I approach this by installing (from source if preferable) from a disk?

Comment: http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-dvd.html

Comment: Thanks johannes! I wan't aware of the DVD. If you post , I will accept that answer.